# Give different shapes the same color based on attributes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attribute-table, arcgis-10.4, color

I am working with ArcMap 10.4 and have some issues. I'm making a Floodmap based for Europe and want to color the shapes related to the total amount of floods in every polygon. For example I have Czech Republic where 3 of the 8 shapes has 5 floods as a total amount in the attribute table. Is it possible to give these 3 shapes (and all the other ones with 5 floods) automatically the same (orange) color?

Comment: Have you checked this link https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/create-maps/change-style.htm

Answer (score 3):

its possible to give polygons styles based on attributes. Right click on your layer in the table of contents. Choose properties, then the Symbology tab. If you choose Categories, then unique values you can choose a style based on the contents of a field that you choose.

Comment: Yes that's possible, but i'm working with different layers because of the other data in the attribute tabels. So I want to add the same color to different layers with the same amount of floodevents

Comment: OK, not so easy then - you can manually apply the same style to each layer, but that is obviously a pain if you've got lots of layers. Can you merge all the data into one table - Arc lets you match fields manually if your flood events data is in fields with different names?

Answer (score 0):

Do the different layers have the same attributes? If so you can import symbology between them:

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-layers/importing-symbology-from-another-layer.htm